Medians from rows of numbers
You have three rows of numbers, $(a_1,a_2,a_3), (b_1,b_2,b_3), (c_1,c_2,c_3)$, each in the range $[0,1]$ and summing up to $1$. If the medians of the three columns are $m_1,m_2,m_3$ with sum $m$, you write one more row, $\left(\dfrac{m_1}{m}, \dfrac{m_2}{m}, \dfrac{m_3}{m}\right)$.
Is it always true that among all possible rows you can write (three numbers in $[0,1]$ summing up to $1$), the row you wrote minimizes the sum of distances to $(a_1,a_2,a_3), (b_1,b_2,b_3), (c_1,c_2,c_3)$? (Here the distance between two rows is just the maximum of the absolute differences of elements, like $\max\{|a_1-b_1|,|a_2-b_2|,|a_3-b_3|\}$.)
This seems to be true from experiments, but casework does get messy as there are many possible configurations. For example, $m$ could be more than, less than, or equal to $1$. Is there a way to reduce the casework or prove this in some other way?
